# PHP Accessing keys in array in php and checking if they exist then do something

Tags: php, arrays

I am really new at this.
I have this json data

```
[phone_numbers] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => home
                [value] => 123456
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => work
                [value] => 678910
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => mobile
                [value] => 1029384675
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [type] => other
                [value] => 18737540
            )

    )
```

I want to check to see if the keys exist and print them if they do exist. And print "N/A" if they don't exist

I have this code - it may not be an elegant way do to it.

```
if (array_key_exists(0,['phone_numbers']))
{
Print "Phone " . $cust_data ['phone_numbers'][0]['type'] . ": " . 
$cust_data['phone_numbers'][0]['value'] . "<br>";
  }
else
  {
  print "Phone N/A";
}

if (array_key_exists(1,['phone_numbers']))
{
    Print "Phone " . $cust_data ['phone_numbers'][1]['type'] . ": " . 
$cust_data['phone_numbers'][1]['value'] . "<br>";
}
else
  {
print "Phone N/A";
}
```

The first print statement works, the second does not.
If I take the second `print` statment out of the second `if` statement it does work.

So the question is why it does not work inside the second `if`.
Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Your code works here - https://3v4l.org/JNJ22. It assumes that `['phone_numbers']` in `array_key_exists(0,['phone_numbers'])` and `array_key_exists(1,['phone_numbers'])`  is actually `$cust_data['phone_numbers']`

Comment: Thanks Sean
Would the PHP version make a difference? 
PHP 7.1.8 on Xampp / OS windows

Yes the keys /values exist
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this more flexible, I've changed the way it looks at the data.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$cust_data = array(
        'phone_numbers' => array(
                array('type' => 'home', 'value' => 123456),
                array('type' => 'work', 'value' => 678910),
                array('type' => 'mobile', 'value' => 1029384675),
                array('type' => 'other', 'value' => 18737540)
        )
);
$phoneTypes = ['home', 'work', 'mobile', 'other'];
$phoneList = array_column($cust_data['phone_numbers'], 'value', 'type');
foreach ( $phoneTypes as $phoneType )   {
    if ( isset($phoneList[ $phoneType ]))    {
        echo "Phone ".$phoneType.": ".$phoneList[ $phoneType ]."<br />";
    }
    else    {
        echo "Phone ".$phoneType.": N/A<br />";
    }
}
```

To ensure that it doesn't just miss out empty elements, I've changed it to have a list of the possible types of numbers to expect ($phoneTypes) and then converted the initial data to be an array indexed by the type (the array_column call).

Then I go through each of the possible phone types and check if that particular one is set, outputting the number or N/A as appropriate.

The advantage of this is that it's not dependant of the position in the array, so if you removed the mobile number, this would still work and put N/A for the mobile number.

Also for consistency - the numbers are always put out in the same order, doesn't matter how your source data is organised.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because of the syntax of `array_key_exits()`. 
Try like this.

```
    $cust_data = array(
        'phone_numbers' => array(
            array('type' => 'home', 'value' => 9876543210),
            array('type' => 'work', 'value' => 78734464546),
            array('type' => 'mobile', 'value' => 1234567890),
            array('type' => 'other', 'value' => 9876343630)
        )
    );
    if ( array_key_exists (0, $cust_data['phone_numbers'])){
        Print "Phone " . $cust_data ['phone_numbers'][0]['type'] . ": " . 
            $cust_data['phone_numbers'][0]['value'] . "<br>";
    }
    else {
        print "Phone N/A";
    }
    if (array_key_exists(1, $cust_data['phone_numbers'])){
        Print "Phone " . $cust_data ['phone_numbers'][1]['type'] . ": " . 
            $cust_data['phone_numbers'][1]['value'] . "<br>";
    } else {
        print "Phone N/A";
    }
```